# linux + dropped value from ifconfig

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig, dropped

please advice what could be the root cause for dropped problem
as the following: ( dropped 2201101 ) on Linux red-hat 7.1

```
    eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
    inet 12.196.92.19  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 12.196.92.255
    ether 01:j0:56:9f:01:2d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 232527230  bytes 1889668645608 (1.7 TiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 2201101  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 197267008  bytes 455540267580 (424.2 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



  ethtool -S eth1
  NIC statistics:
  Tx Queue#: 0
     TSO pkts tx: 0
     TSO bytes tx: 0
     ucast pkts tx: 27261
     ucast bytes tx: 5684138
     mcast pkts tx: 0
     mcast bytes tx: 0
     bcast pkts tx: 6
     bcast bytes tx: 252
     pkts tx err: 0
     pkts tx discard: 0
     drv dropped tx total: 0
       too many frags: 0
       giant hdr: 0
       hdr err: 0
       tso: 0
     ring full: 0
     pkts linearized: 0
     hdr cloned: 0
     giant hdr: 0
    Tx Queue#: 1
      TSO pkts tx: 0
      TSO bytes tx: 0
      ucast pkts tx: 138
      ucast bytes tx: 12312
      mcast pkts tx: 0
      mcast bytes tx: 0
      bcast pkts tx: 0
      bcast bytes tx: 0
      pkts tx err: 0
      pkts tx discard: 0
      drv dropped tx total: 0
         too many frags: 0
         giant hdr: 0
         hdr err: 0
         tso: 0
      ring full: 0
      pkts linearized: 0
      hdr cloned: 0
      giant hdr: 0
    Rx Queue#: 0
      LRO pkts rx: 0
      LRO byte rx: 0
      ucast pkts rx: 123
      ucast bytes rx: 10936
      mcast pkts rx: 0
      mcast bytes rx: 0
      bcast pkts rx: 13496
      bcast bytes rx: 859036
      pkts rx OOB: 0
      pkts rx err: 0
     drv dropped rx total: 0
        err: 0
       fcs: 0
       rx buf alloc fail: 0
      Rx Queue#: 1
      LRO pkts rx: 2613
      LRO byte rx: 40902978
      ucast pkts rx: 27979
      ucast bytes rx: 128670918
      mcast pkts rx: 0
      mcast bytes rx: 0
      bcast pkts rx: 255
      bcast bytes rx: 34445
      pkts rx OOB: 0
      pkts rx err: 0
      drv dropped rx total: 0
      err: 0
      fcs: 0
      rx buf alloc fail: 0
      tx timeout count: 0
```

Comment: Solar flares would be my guess

Comment: can you advice, what is Solar flares?

Comment: is this patch that need to install or maybe configuration in the network files??

Comment: I find it --> unzip SF‐107601‐LS‐<version>_Solarflare_Linux_Utilities_RPM_64bit.zip  , can I installed it on VM machine ?? ,

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of drop and errors causes with their counters using the following command (show interface statistics):

```
$ ethtool -S eth1
```

Comment: I run the ethtool , as you see here , but how to identify the problem from the output?